# Very slow initialisation of AWS SDK in development environment

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, macos, amazon-s3

My team has been using this SDK with CodeIgniter for a couple of years with no issues until now. I recently transitioned to a Mac Mini & set up my local development environment on the machine & now the SDK is being painfully slow. Initialising it via the `Aws\S3\S3Client` constructor takes around 18 seconds. It's very consistent with this; almost always 18 seconds. Every so often it takes 17 seconds, but the rest is 18.
I'm the only one in my team using macOS & the only one having this problem; we even recreated the environment on a Windows machine & there is no problems with the SDK. Same project structure, same environment variables. The only difference is the operating system using XAMPP on Windows.

**Expected Behavior**

The SDK should initialise in a timely manner.

**Current Behavior**

The SDK takes a lengthy amount of time to initialise.

**Reproduction Steps**

1. Install SDK via Composer: `composer require aws/aws-sdk-php`
2. Add a script to the project to use the SDK

```
<?php

use Aws\Exception\AwsException;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

class Aws_sdk
{
    private $s3;

    public function __construct()
    {
        try {
            $t        = time();
            $this->s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
                'version'     => 'latest',
                'region'      => 'ap-southeast-2',
                'credentials' => [
                    // I'm obviously using the proper keys in my project.
                    'key'    => 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
                    'secret' => 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
                ]
            ]);
            printf('Took %d seconds', time() - $t);
            exit;
        } catch (Throwable $t) {
            echo $t->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

3. Run project

[image: The result of running my project.]

**Additional Information/Context**

As I stated, this is only happening on my machine across projects. All projects we have that is using this SDK will take approximately 18 seconds to initialise on my machine, but works as expected on all others. It's also consistent; I can reproduce it every time.

What I've done to investigate & try to fix the issue:

1. Set up brand new local development environment.
2. Reinstalled/reinitialised everything a couple of times: CodeIgniter, composer, the SDK, the project etc.
3. Flushed caches were applicable.
4. Tried to replicate the issue on different machines/operating systems.

Also, I don't know if it's relevant, but I've tried every approach possible to defining the credentials as outlined [here in the Using the Default Credential Provider Chain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials.html). For the sake of removing layers of code for this issue, I've hard coded the credentials until I've gotten it fixed.

**Environment details**

AWS SDK version: 3.227

PHP version: 7.4.28

OS: macOS Monterey 12.4

Composer version: 2.1.9 2021-10-05 09:47:38

CodeIgniter version: 3.1.11

Comment: P.S. I've asked this on the official GitHub repository as well. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/2474